# Parametrize the contours of integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am having a difficult time figuring this problem out:

Parametrize the contours of integration and write the integrals in terms of the parametrizations.

$$\int_{\Gamma} (3\bar{z}^2+2z^3)\,dz$$

where $\Gamma$ is a straight line segment that joins $1-2i$ (initial point) and $3+4i$ (terminal point).

I would appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers, what does $t\mapsto a(1-t) + bt$ for $t\in[0,1]$ do?

Comment: In all honesty I'm not quite sure. I've been in over my head with this topic and I feel like I'm missing something. I know when we were finding the parametrization in class we were looking at a smooth curve that consisted of three smooth pieces. 

Based on that example and my notes I wrote:

1-2i + t(2+6i) 2<t<4 

I did this using the terminal and initial points of the straight line segment. I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Plot an example. You will see this draws a straight line connecting $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

The straight line from $1-2i$ to $3+4i$ is given by the parameterization $\gamma(t)=(1-2i)(1-t)+(3+4i)t = 1+2t +i(6t-2)$ where $t \in [0,1]$
We have $dz=(2+6i)dt$
What does the integral come down to? Fill in the placeholders:
$$
\int_0^1(3(\cdot)^2+2(\cdot)^3)(\cdot)dt
$$

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!